# Svelte tanstack table pagination?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, tanstack

I'm trying to make the table pagination in svelte to work but for some reason i'm getting a safeUpdater function instead of PaginationState (which is what i expected). How do i keep track of the latest `pageIndex` if i couldn't get the proper result from onPaginationChange method that i passed to `createSvelteTable`?[image]

Comment: It would be a little more helpful to show a little bit of code, but what you can try to use is a svelte store that can be manipulated when the tab is changed, here's the tutorial about that: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores